# How to run random gif maker python script?

Tags: python, random, gif

I don't know much about python but I found a script that claims to do what I need to, problem is that I have no idea how to running it.
https://github.com/Friss/random-gif-maker
It's a Random Gif Maker which works via Python, I run it via terminal ($ python /routetoscript/randomGif.py). I don't know if I have to edit some fields or if it suppose to be somekind "automatic". Help please!

Comment: It says to run `python randomGif.py`.  Then enter the path to your movies/video files

Comment: It throws me this error after the path to movies: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: You could try posting an issue on that repository.  The author can either fix it if it is a bug, or he can help you if it isn't.